# sub-domain tries to access a non existing typo3 installation

Tags: php, iis, typo3

I have the following dir structure in my Server 2019 IIS.
C:\inetpub\wwwroot\typo3  main Typo3 Web site
C:\inetpub\wwwroot\typo3\Homepage  second Typo3 Web site
C:\inetpub\wwwroot\typo3\Homepage\ahnen webtrees web site

If I call the webtrees via https://www.myUrl.de/ahnen it works fine.
But if I try to use the sub-domain https://ahnen.myUrl.de I got the following error message:

> Warning:
> require(C:/inetpub/wwwroot/Homepage/ahnen/typo3/sysext/core/Configuration/DefaultConfiguration.php):
> failed to open stream: No such file or directory in
> C:\inetpub\wwwroot\typo3\sysext\core\Classes\Configuration\ConfigurationManager.php
> on line 92 Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required
> 'C:/inetpub/wwwroot/Homepage/ahnen/typo3/sysext/core/Configuration/DefaultConfiguration.php'
> (include_path='.;C:\php\pear') in
> C:\inetpub\wwwroot\typo3\sysext\core\Classes\Configuration\ConfigurationManager.php
> on line 92

The setup of the sub-domain pointed to the same folder than https://www.myUrl.de/ahnen, as you could see in the error message.
But I have absolutely no idea, why the system is expecting a typo3 installation.
What could be create this problem?

Comment: There is a similar problem in this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36577020/php-failed-to-open-stream-no-such-file-or-directory

Answer (score 0):

For an exact answer you provide to less information (and I might need more knowledge about IIS configuration)

I assume that https://www.myUrl.de points to an TYPO3 installation and that you want https://ahnen.myUrl.de to point to a subfolder of the webroot of that TYPO3 installation.

1. possibility: the 'subfolder' `ahnen/` is no real subfolder but a page inside your TYPO3 installation
   then your ISS configuration points to a not existing folder in your filesystem. you have a fallback to nearest page and get a configuration conflict as your domain ahnen.myUrl.de is unknown to your TYPO3 installation.
2. possibility: there is a subfolder `ahnen/` inside your primary webroot and there also is a TYPO3 installation, which might be misconfigured about the webroot of that subdomain, resulting in mismatched folders for resources.
3. possibility: your ISS configuration does not handle the subdomain correctly and starts the primary TYPO3 with not matching domain and folders, so TYPO3 becomes confused about locations of resources.